# Shortly or instantly?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I want to know which one of those words is more suitable to use when I get something without waiting?

For example:

> We will receive the result ____, no waiting!

My first guess is instantly, but I don't see why shortly will be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly will not do here, because shortly implies that there will be a short time intervall.